# Webservice callout causing test failures

Tags: apex, unit-test, webservices

I am trying to implement Bitly into our business process within Salesforce for getfeedback URLs. I have created the test class to cover the code I found at https://douglascayers.com/2015/10/21/salesforce-create-short-urls-with-bitly-process-builder-and-apex/. However this has now caused some of my other tests to fail with the following

> Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts.

I keep reading that I am suppose to take any DML statements out of `test.starttest()` and `test.stoptest()` and use `Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator())` and I keep seeing this page https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm. However what I don't understand is that if I take DML statement out then I am not longer testing my code.

eg:

```
    test.starttest();      
    opp1.StageName = 'Review Complete';
    //test other apex code creating new records when opp is closed as Review Complete
    update opp1;
    test.stoptest();
```

Can someone please help explain what I am suppose to do so that I can still test my DML statements and not run into this error message. I am using the test code from this thread: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MKfgIAG

Answer (score 0):

There are two challenges in testing callouts:

- The actual callout can't be made from a test: the best solution to this is to mock the callout but if absolutely necessary you can just not make the callout when running tests by adding a `Test.isRunningTest()` guard in the code that makes the callout
- The platform does not allow DML before a callout in a transaction (presumably because a callout can be long-running which would mean expensive to the platform long-lived transactions) but there is a pattern in tests that works around this

The pattern in tests makes use of methods of the Apex [Test Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm?search_text=startTest). You can do the necessary DML first like this:

```
// Do required DML

Test.startTest();

Test.setMock(...);

// Call code that does callout

Test.stopTest();
```

See [Performing DML Operations and Mock Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing_dml.htm) for more explanation.

Comment: I think I am still confused, I have one trigger point as an example. It triggers both a record to be created via apex and a callout. with your example with the DML outside wont the record created via apex no longer be covered?

Comment: I tried the Test.isRunningTest() before I posted as well but I think its the same as I mentioned above. my tests now pass but my apex being triggered to do other stuff is no longer covered.

Comment: @Michael Best to post the relevant bits of your code. But if the trigger is kicking off the callout in an `future` then all you can do is add the Test.isRunningTest() guard to the trigger and write a separate test for the callout method.